# Generate HTML with JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm quite new to JavaScript so I don't understand what's not working.
The Code:

```
var postCount = 0;

function generatePost(title, time, text) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "content";
    div.id = "post_" + postCount;
    document.getElementById("postcontainer").appendChild(div);

    var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    div.id = "post_h3_" + postCount;
    h3.innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById("post_" + postCount).appendChild(div);

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    document.getElementById("post_h3_" + postCount).appendChild(div);
    span.innerHTML = time;

    var paragraphs[] = text.split("||");
    for (var p : paragraphs[] {
        var paragraphCount = 0;
        var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
        document.getElementById("post_p_" + postCount + "_" + paragraphCount).appendChild(div);
        paragraphCount++;
    }
    postCount++;
}

function loadPosts() {
    generatePost("Testing Title", "I don't know", "This is || a paragraph");
}
```

I included it with:

```
<body onload="loadPosts()">
```

In the end, nothing shows up. Not even in the Inspector in my Browser. Is my Code even run? Did I forget an essential doStuffNow()?

Second: If I add a class to a div with JavaScript, do the CSS-Rules in the style.css append to it?

Comment: If you format your code it appears that you have an extra or misplaced closing brace: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/m5j4sjsk/

Comment: No, a missing right paren: `for (var p: paragraphs[]) {`

Comment: Instead of adding the function on the onload of your body you should wrap your code into something that in called when the DOM is loaded like this. `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {// YOUR_CODE_HERE})` And then simply call the function `generatePost`, no need for the `loadPosts` function.

Comment: Where are your other elements such as "postcontainer"?

Comment: postcontainer is a div with the id postcontainer, It is where it's meant to be.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second part of your question, **yes**, the CSS styling that applies to a class will be added to an object that you add the same class to.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your code. What editor do you use? You can also use browser console to check for errors in your page.
Check here:

```
var paragraphs = text.split("||");
for (var p in paragraphs) {
    /*
    *
    * Where do you use your var p?
    *
    */
    var paragraphCount = 0;
    var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    document.getElementById("post_p_" + postCount + "_" + paragraphCount).appendChild(div);
    paragraphCount++;
}
```

Why don't you try with jQuery?

Comment: I'm using Brackets from Adobe which is not good for PHP and/or JavaScript yet.
I didn't use jQuery because it's an API, another file, website = slower.

Comment: Use CDN. The minified version is less than 50kb, which is downloaded pretty fast with nowadays connections :)

Comment: Try PhpStorm, SublimeText, Netbeans for programming

Comment: Brackets has a Live-Preview, so if you edit something it is immediately edited on your preview. It's quite awesome for editing HTML and CSS.

Comment: Use inspect elements in your browser, or FireBug addon. But if Brackets doesn't show you your errors, you should get another one

Comment: It shows them... for HTML and CSS. Whatever, any other thoughts on my problem?